# OpenCV functions lock when called by a Python script itself called by a C++ threaded program

Tags: python, c++, multithreading, opencv

I have a `C++` application calling `Python` functions from several threads.
Everything works fine until I try to use an `OpenCV` function from within `Python`:

- If called in the same thread the interpreter was initialized in, it works fine
- If called in any other `C++` thread, it locks forever, waiting for a mutex to be released

Basically I have two files:

**script.py:**

```
import cv2

def foo():
    print('foo_in')
    cv2.imread('sample.jpg')
    print('foo_out')
```

**main.cpp:**

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <pybind11/embed.h>

pybind11::handle g_main;

void* foo(void*)
{
    g_main.attr("foo")();
}

int main()
{
    pybind11::scoped_interpreter guard;
    pybind11::eval_file("script.py");
    g_main = pybind11::module::import("__main__");

    foo(nullptr);

    pthread_t thread;
    pthread_create(&thread, nullptr, &foo, nullptr);
    pthread_join(thread, nullptr);

    return 0;
}
```

And when I execute the C++ snippet I get:

```
foo_in
foo_out
foo_in
```

...and then it gets stuck forever.

As you can see the first call to `cv2.imread` returns but not the second one (the one called in an other thread).

When I `strace` the thread PID I get the following lines:

```
futex(0x7fe7e6b3e364, FUTEX_WAIT_BITSET_PRIVATE|FUTEX_CLOCK_REALTIME, 13961, {1550596187, 546432000}, ffffffff) = -1 ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
futex(0x7fe7e6b3e3e0, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 0
```

...printed again and again, which makes me think the thread is waiting for a mutex to be released.

I further tried to understand what was going on by using the backtrace of `gdb`:

```
#0  pthread_cond_timedwait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/pthread_cond_timedwait.S:225
#1  0x00007fe7e667948f in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.5m.so.1.0
#2  0x00007fe7e6679979 in PyEval_RestoreThread () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.5m.so.1.0
#3  0x00007fe7e669968b in PyGILState_Ensure () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.5m.so.1.0
#4  0x00007fe7e3fa7635 in PyEnsureGIL::PyEnsureGIL (this=<synthetic pointer>) at <opencv>/modules/python/src2/cv2.cpp:83
#5  NumpyAllocator::deallocate (this=<optimized out>, u=0x7fe7a80008c0) at <opencv>/modules/python/src2/cv2.cpp:208
#6  0x00007fe7d88e17c2 in cv::MatAllocator::unmap (this=<optimized out>, u=<optimized out>) at <opencv>/modules/core/src/matrix.cpp:18
#7  0x00007fe7e3fa7dc8 in cv::Mat::release (this=0x7fe7ae8018e0) at <opencv>/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/mat.inl.hpp:808
#8  cv::Mat::~Mat (this=0x7fe7ae8018e0, __in_chrg=<optimized out>) at <opencv>/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/mat.inl.hpp:694
#9  pyopencv_from<cv::Mat> (m=...) at <opencv>/modules/python/src2/cv2.cpp:451
#10 0x00007fe7e3faa08c in pyopencv_cv_imread (args=<optimized out>, kw=<optimized out>) at <opencv>/build/modules/python_bindings_generator/pyopencv_generated_funcs.h:10588
#11 0x00007fe7e6575049 in PyCFunction_Call () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.5m.so.1.0
#12 0x00007fe7e66811c5 in PyEval_EvalFrameEx () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.5m.so.1.0
#13 0x00007fe7e6711cbc in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.5m.so.1.0
#14 0x00007fe7e6711d93 in PyEval_EvalCodeEx () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.5m.so.1.0
#15 0x00007fe7e6599ac8 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.5m.so.1.0
#16 0x00007fe7e664e55e in PyObject_Call () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.5m.so.1.0
#17 0x00007fe7e6710947 in PyEval_CallObjectWithKeywords () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.5m.so.1.0
#18 0x00000000004369de in pybind11::detail::simple_collector<(pybind11::return_value_policy)1>::call (this=0x7fe7ae801e80, ptr=0x7fe7e6eaef28) at <pybind11>/pybind11/cast.h:1953
#19 0x00000000004334f3 in pybind11::detail::object_api<pybind11::detail::accessor<pybind11::detail::accessor_policies::str_attr> >::operator()<(pybind11::return_value_policy)1> (this=0x7fe7ae801ed0)
    at <pybind11>/pybind11/cast.h:2108
#20 0x0000000000424336 in foo () at main.cpp:11
```

I tried moving the python interpreter initialization into the `foo` function and then it worked (I just had to remove the first call to `foo` as the interpreter can only be initialized once per application).

This makes me think that the `cv2.imread` function only returns if called in the same thread the interpreter was initialized in.

The same happens if I replace the call to `cv2.imread` by any other OpenCV function.
I tested it on `cv2.imwrite` and `cv2.projectPoints`.

Any idea of what is happening and how I can get around it while still being able to call OpenCV functions from different threads?

Comment: No idea about the deadlock.... But why are you calling OpenCV Python functions from C++ (you are calling from C++ a Python wrapper over C++ functions)? Can't you just use OpenCV directly in C++?

Comment: Can you inspect the GIL to see who *does* own it?

Comment: @Miki the sample code I provided is just a case example. In the real project I am facing this issue, I mix a lot of Numpy, OpenCV and other libraries calls inside a Python script which is itself called from the main C++ application. It would be burdensome to go back and forth between C++ and Python everytime I need using an OpenCV function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it turned out the problem was me using Python instructions without holding the GIL (Global Interpreter Lock). The GIL is first held by the thread initializing the interpreter and must be explicitly released before other threads can acquire it.

The reason the execution locked on the `cv2.imread` instruction and not the `print('foo_in')` instruction is that the Python interpreter does not ensure it is holding the GIL when called from C++ (which means that any pure Python instruction is executed in a thread-unsafe way). However the C++ code called by the `cv2.*` instructions under the hood does make sure it is holding the GIL before executing, hence the lock.

I fixed the problem using explicit GIL release and acquisition:

**main.cpp**

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <pybind11/embed.h>

pybind11::handle g_main;

void* foo(void*)
{
    pybind11::gil_scoped_acquire gil;
    g_main.attr("foo")();
}

int main()
{
    pybind11::scoped_interpreter guard;
    pybind11::eval_file("../script.py");
    g_main = pybind11::module::import("__main__");
    pybind11::gil_scoped_release nogil;

    foo(nullptr);

    pthread_t thread;
    pthread_create(&thread, nullptr, &foo, nullptr);
    pthread_join(thread, nullptr);

    return 0;
}
```

Now everything works fine and I do get the expected output:

```
foo_in
foo_out
foo_in
foo_out
```